# How to use session in PHP with variables

Tags: php

I want to display the username from a database using `$_SESSION` in `php`.

In my project there is one table which stores all the information for login and logout and from that table want to display the username in ever php page

Comment: use `$_SESSION['']`... you need this `session_start()` to run a session.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

A PHP session is easily started by making a call to the session_start() function.This function first checks if a session is already started and if none is started then it starts one. It is recommended to put the call to session_start() at the beginning of the page.

Session variables are stored in associative array called $_SESSION[]. These variables can be accessed during lifetime of a session.

The following example starts a session then register a variable called counter that is incremented each time the page is visited during the session.

Make use of isset() function to check if session variable is already set or not.

Put this code in a test.php file and load this file many times to see the result −

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if( isset( $_SESSION['counter'] ) )
   {
      $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
   }
   else
   {
      $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
   }
   $msg = "You have visited this page ".  $_SESSION['counter'];
   $msg .= "in this session.";
?>
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Setting up a PHP session</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php  echo ( $msg ); ?>
   </body>

</html>
```

Destroying a PHP Session

A PHP session can be destroyed by session_destroy() function. This function does not need any argument and a single call can destroy all the session variables. If you want to destroy a single session variable then you can use unset() function to unset a session variable.

Here is the example to unset a single variable −

```
<?php
   unset($_SESSION['counter']);
?>
```

Here is the call which will destroy all the session variables −

```
<?php
   session_destroy();
?>
```

Turning on Auto Session
You don't need to call start_session() function to start a session when a user visits your site if you can set session.auto_start variable to 1 in php.ini file.

Sessions without cookies
There may be a case when a user does not allow to store cookies on their machine. So there is another method to send session ID to the browser.

Alternatively, you can use the constant SID which is defined if the session started. If the client did not send an appropriate session cookie, it has the form session_name=session_id. Otherwise, it expands to an empty string. Thus, you can embed it unconditionally into URLs.

The following example demonstrates how to register a variable, and how to link correctly to another page using SID.

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
      $_SESSION['counter'] = 1;
   }
   else {
      $_SESSION['counter']++;
   }

   $msg = "You have visited this page ".  $_SESSION['counter'];
   $msg .= "in this session.";

   echo ( $msg );
?>
<p>
   To continue  click following link <br />

   <a  href="nextpage.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>">
</p>
```

Ref:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sessions.htm